# Почему throws не обрабатывается?

Tags: java, android, исключения

Есть следующий код:

**DefaultAnimationComposer.java**

```
public class DefaultAnimationComposer implements AnimationComposer{

    private ArrayList<AnimationAction> animationCollection = new ArrayList<>();
    private volatile boolean  isWorking = true;

    @Override
    public void addAnimation(AnimationAction animation){
        animationCollection.add(animation);
        animation.subscribe(this);
        animation.setDelay();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnded(AnimationAction animation){

        try{
            new Handler().postDelayed(() -> animationCollection.get(animationIndex + 1).executeAction(), delay);
        }catch(NullPointerException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            onAnimationEnded(animationCollection.get(animationIndex + 1));
        }

    }
}
```

**SomeClass.java**

```
animationComposer.addAnimation(new AnimationAction(){
                @Override
                public void executeAction() throws NullPointerException{
                        doneView.setAlpha(1f);
                        doneView.setSpeed(0.7f);
                        doneView.playAnimation();
                        Log.d(TESTING_TAG, "executeAction()2 in RegisterFragment");
                        doneView.addAnimatorListener(new ExecuteNextAfterEndListener(animationComposer, this));
                }

                @Override
                public void setDelay(){
                    delay = 100;
                }
            });
```

При пересоздании экрана `doneView` становится `Null`. Соот-но метод `setAlpha()` должен выбрасывать `NullPointerException`, а эта ошибка должна обрабатываться в `onAnimationEnded()` в классе `DefaultAnimationComposer`, однако этого почему-то не происходит.

**UPD:**

Обновил код, однако все равно не работает.

```
animationComposer.addAnimation(new AnimationAction(){
            @Override
            public void executeAction() throws NullPointerException{
                try{
                    doneView.setAlpha(1f);
                    doneView.setSpeed(0.7f);
                    doneView.playAnimation();
                    Log.d(TESTING_TAG, "executeAction()2 in RegisterFragment");
                    doneView.addAnimatorListener(new ExecuteNextAfterEndListener(animationComposer, this));
                }catch(NullPointerException ex){
                    subject.onAnimationEnded(this);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void setDelay(){
                delay = 100;
            }
        });
```

***Stacktrace***

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setAlpha(float)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at android.view.View$2.setValue(View.java:20818)
                                                                                at android.view.View$2.setValue(View.java:20815)
                                                                                at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$FloatPropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesHolder.java:1288)
                                                                                at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:981)
                                                                                at android.animation.ValueAnimator.animationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1384)
                                                                                at android.animation.ValueAnimator.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1427)
                                                                                at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:759)
                                                                                at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler$1.run(ValueAnimator.java:801)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:672)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:605)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:846)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5549)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:742)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:632)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таких случаях не `NullPointerException` мониторят, а делают проверку на `null`:

```
    if (doneView != null) {
        // что-то делаем
    } else {
        // делаем другое
    }
```

Comment: Я уже пробовал так делать и не помогало. Сейчас вспомни, что если у нас doneView == null, надо делать return. Вопрос закрыт

Answer (score 3):

Вы не в том потоке и не для тех инструкций ловите ошибку.

1. Во первых вы ловите ошибку только для синхронных вызовов методов при отправке события в очередь

   ```
   new Handler().postDelayed(...); //тут поймаются только ошибки метода postDelayed или его аргументов
   ```
2. Во вторых, ошибки, которые будут выброшены в других потоках или коллбэках, т.е. асинхронно, надо ловить в местах их возникновения. Т.е. `catch` блок в вашем коде не будет ждать неопределённое время пока выполняться или нет какие-то неизвестные инструкции в неизвестных потоках.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.